# iptables does not list rules i have created

Tags: iptables

I'm using [this guide](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_Share) to set-up a shared internet connection between two PC's.

At **step 8** it says I should run the commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/etc/rc.d/iptables save
/etc/rc.d/iptables start
```

Doing this seems to have no effect on iptable's **rules**, if I run `iptables -nvL` my output is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2223 packets, 2330K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source         destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source        destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2272 packets, 277K bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source        destination
```

Is that correct or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The command `iptables -nvL` is displaying the contents of the `filter` table. The rule you are adding is in the `nat` table. Add `-t nat` to look at the `nat` table:

```
iptables -t nat -nvL
```

Comment: Thanks, I was checking the wrong table, that worked

Answer (score 4):

You can also run `iptables-save` and it'll dump all the contents to the screen if you just want to look at everything.  I find it easy to look at everything that way when I feel lazy.

Comment: I don't get why my INPUT rule does not appear when I use `iptables -L` but does show up when using `iptables-save`. Makes no sense.

Comment: iptables-save just dumps everything but iptables -L (without the -t directive) defaults to JUST showing your filter table.  There are 3 other tables which CAN be listed https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables